# Entering multiple parameters manually, separated by comma

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that can take multiple order numbers as parameters, and returns a subreport for each one.  Currently, I have a query that runs first that populates the parameter list with all possible order numbers, and you can scroll and select which ones you want.  I would rather have it that you just enter in the order #s, all separated by a comma.. I do not know how to set this up.  Can someone please help?

Comment: You can use two parameters one internal and other visible. For visible parameter use text data type. Ensure your user type the order numbers separated by commas. Then in the internal parameter use `Split()` by commas over internal parameter. Pass the internal parameter to the query you want to filter. For further help edit your question and include more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the parameter datatype as text, then create a split string function and then the user could enter all the values separated by a comma.

your where clause would look like this-

```
WHERE Parameter IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split_String( @Parameter, ','))
```

Split String Function-

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_String]
(
@List nvarchar(max),
@token nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
--Id int identity(1,1),
Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN

SET @List = RTRIM(LTRIM(@List))
IF @List <> '' 
BEGIN
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@token, @List)>0)
    BEGIN 

        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
        SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List,1,CHARINDEX(@token,@List)-1))) 

        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,CHARINDEX(@token,@List)+LEN(@token),LEN(@List))

    END 

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
    SELECT Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))
END

RETURN
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the multiple values option in a parameter?

### Set up the parameter

Setup a simple generic parameter like displayed in the figure below:

[image]

The key component is the **Allow multiple values** option that will allow you type multiple text values into your parameter.

### Update the dataset

Then in your dataset, make sure you add the `WHERE` clause like so.

```
WHERE orders.ordernumber IN (@OrderNumbers)
```

This will ensure your data is filtered to the typed in order numbers. The `IN` comparison is important because the `@OrderNumbers` parameter *could* contain more than one value. Multi-value parameters are also considered as collections/arrays and therefore attempting to use `=` will result in a type mismatch.

### Testing

The data input is slightly different to what you hoped since we will be using carriage returns to separate the order numbers rather than commas.

[image]

However, when the textbox loses focus it will format the appearance of the text back to commas.

[image]

**Please note: you need to select the drop-down arrow before you can start typing in the textbox. You cannot type values with the parameter drop-down collapsed.**